# Google chart rollover edit text?

Tags: annotations, google-visualization

Another Google Chart related question this time I like to edit the onrollover annotation. At the moment it shows the function which i like to remove and i like to show a % , in this case 96.40%

[image]

Oh and I notice this Google Start doesn't plot / start and ends with the right month. It starts in March en ends in July (but should be Feb - Jun)

```
data.addRows([
                    [new Date(2017 ,02) ,100.00,'100.00'],[new Date(2017 ,03) ,100.00,'100.00'],[new Date(2017 ,04) ,100.00,'100.00'],[new Date(2017 ,05) ,100.00,'100.00'],[new Date(2017 ,06) ,87.50,'87.50']
]);
```

[image]

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48014750/5090771), which replaces the function with "CUSTOM TEXT" -- you could probably use a similar routine to add the "%"...

Comment: @WhiteHat tx going to see how you fixed that one. Meanwhile do you know why the date is from Mar to Jul and not Feb to Jun (see my data rows and image)?

Comment: in javascript, the month number is zero-based --> `0 = Jan`, `1 = Feb`, `2 = Mar`...

Comment: yeah, tx after a quick shower I also realized myself I parsed the Chart data with PHP date function like  date('m', strtotime('Mar') ) which turns to 03 ,